# Simple Proof of the Arctic Circle Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

Does anyone know a straightforward proof of the [Arctic Circle Theorem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801068.pdf) using the height function or any other method? I have tried to find one, but I only managed to dig up long papers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no straightforward proof.  [This paper](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/p1.pdf) by Pemantle & Wilson (Ex. 3.6) provides a good outline of the most direct approach.  First one obtains a closed form multivariate GF for local statistics.  This can be done in several ways, including a reasonably concise combinatorial approach.  Then one uses the asymptotic analysis.  This can also be done in several ways, none particularly obvious.  See refs in the paper.